# При компиляции проекта выдает ошибку:"java.exe" exited with code 3

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Я уже делал все возможные махинации с расположением jdk и в cmd у меня javac работает как должно.Выдает вот это:

Creating C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk

2>  App4.Android -> C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\App4\App4\App4.Android\bin\Debug\App4.Android.dll

2>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2664,3): error MSB6006: "javac.exe" exited with code 3.

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Проблема не в Java, а в Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: А Что надо сделать чтобы её убрать ?